# Contour plot with holoviews and bokeh

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I have a data array that I want to plot as countour map with holoviews.
The data shape is `(6000, 35, 123)` the `6000` represents the time, which I want to have as a slider. The `35` and `123` are the x-y axes shape.

I'm trying to follow the examples on the [website](http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Contours.html) like:

```
x,y = np.mgrid[-50:51, -50:51] * 0.05
img = hv.Image(np.sin(x**2+y**3))
example = img + hv.operation.contours(img, levels=5)
example.opts(opts.Contours(cmap='fire', colorbar=True, tools=['hover'], width=325))
```

But I'm not sure how to proceed because I have data to plot, not a function of a meshgrid like in the example.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: If you update your example to include some sample code that generates data of the sort you'd like to visualize, then it would be easier to suggest a solution.  But in any case you just provide your data array where it says `np.sin(x**2+y**3)` above, while also specifying your dimensions, like `hv.Image(dataarray,['x','y'],['time'])`.